# Conditional won't work on GrassGIS python script

Tags: python, grass-gis

I have a conditional in Python script from GRASS but I can not get it to work. No matter if I set m to 1 or 0 it always prints "m must be 1 or 0." like it won't enter the conditional.

Here's the script:

```
m=options['m']

if m==1:
    grass.mapcalc("up=$c+tan($phy)*(($gamma*$z*(cos(slope)^2))-($k*$gamma*$z*sin(slope)*cos(slope))-($z*$gammaw))",
                  z = options['z'],
                  c = options['c'],
                  gamma = options['gamma'],
                  phy = options['phy'],
                  k = options['k'],
                  gammaw = 9.81)
    print ('m is 1')
elif m==0:
    grass.mapcalc("up=$c+tan($phy)*(($gamma*$z*(cos(slope)^2))-($k*$gamma*$z*sin(slope)*cos(slope)))",
                  z = options['z'],
                  c = options['c'],
                  gamma = options['gamma'],
                  phy = options['phy'],
                  k = options['k'])
    print ('m is 0')
else:
    print("m must be 1 or 0.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to convert it to number:

```
m = int(options['m'])
```

But it looks like you want to define it as a flag instead of option, since it can be only True or False, so then you would use it as:

```
if flags['m']:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

See also the manual:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/g.parser.html

Comment: Thank you Anna, i did thought it was something simple but I was really stuck. Thanks for your help!